# Python: Pitfalls of creating a super object

Tags: python, python-2.7

We have found that we have a set of attributes(all are not going to change and pulled from the environment at runtime) exist in majority of our classes.  I tried searching around for this but unfortunately "object" is a very common word.

What type of issues will I cause if I do the following:

```
class MasterObjectv2(object):
     UNIQUE_KEY = getUniqueKey()
     #other properties for all objects in our system
```

or is this better:

```
class MasterObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        object.__init__(self)
        #other properties for all objects in our system
        self.getUniqueKey()
```

or option 3

```
# is that its a really dumb idea to do this.
```

I was thinking about doing the first because I don't have to worry about someone not calling **init** on MasterObject.

Obviously our class would change from

```
class Test(object):
   def __init__(self): 
        self.UNIQUE_KEY = getUniqueKey()
```

to

```
class Test(MasterObject):
    def __init__(self): pass
```

---

**Edit**

These answers dont answer my question.  I am not asking what I should do, I am asking about what are the side effects/things to think about if we were going to go down this path.

I am considering using an environment.* type class but I first want to know what the side effects might be* *if* I go down the other path.

I don't want this to turn into a composition versus inheritance debate... ;)

Comment: Do these attributes vary from class to class?

Comment: We have a system that is multiprocessed, but once the process is kicked off the env vars that we read in (config, env, etc) will not change.

Comment: Why do they need to be class members? Why can't you say `environment.UNIQUE_KEY` instead of `self.UNIQUE_KEY`, for example? Where `environment` is some module you create and import in your other modules.

Comment: Or are these keys different for each object you create?

Comment: Because options 1 and 2 have very different results if `getUniqueKey` returns a different value each time it is called.

Comment: @FogleBird First I am considering using an env type class.  But I first wanted to see the implications of using a MasterObject.  getUniqueKey was just an example, all the values that get setup in MasterObject will be static in the sense they will not change during execution.

Comment: @Nix, don't confuse 'static member(/method)' with 'read-only'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With python you can easily control object *construction* in addition to object *initialization*; for example defining

```
class Master(object):
    def __new__(klass, *args, **kwargs):
        self = object.__new__(klass)
        self.attribute1 = ...
        self.attribute2 = ...
        return self
```

The code in `__new__` is executed before the `__init__` eventually defined in the derived class is started (so it doesn't matter if derived class doesn't call `Master.__init__(self)`). You can use `__new__` to setup some attributes in the instance before the start of `__init__`.

Whether or not this is a reasonable thing to do in your case largely depends on details that you did not provide.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need those as attributes in your actual classes? Sounds like keeping them in some "configuration object" and just accessing it from the classes is a more robust idea.

Prefer to keep inheritance strictly for cases where an *is-a* relationship is implied, which in your case isn't true, AFAIU.

Comment: Yes, we need those in the classes, and we want them contained within the classes for code-ability/readability reasons. I don't want this to turn into a composition versus inheritance debate.

Comment: @Nix: uhm, option 3, then ;-)

Comment: your opinion has been noted, and one thing I guess I need to think about is the memory that is being wasted by inheritance because we *do* care about memory consumption.  Just constantly having to write the same set of common code is uber annoying.

Comment: @Nix: not only memory consumption, but also a performance hit if each instance will start reading the environment. You can of course make it lazy reading (so only the first read does something and the others are free) but that's just similar to having an env/config object instead. Other than that you can of course use inheritance in the way you propose - it *will* work, but IMHO it's an abuse of a language feature for something it was not designed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use option #1 if the attributes are static. Since the attribute is a property of the class and doesn't change from instance to instance, this seems the right choice. You will not cause any issues by going with option #1 (assuming your classes were implemented similar to Test).

```
class MasterObjectv2(object):
     UNIQUE_KEY = getUniqueKey()
     #other properties for all objects in our system
```

Then your Test class could be implemented as follows:

```
class Test(MasterObject):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the values of the attributes, once taken from the environment, be the same for all those classes? If so, you'd probably be better off just keeping a `dict` of those environmental attributes at module level. (Or, as someone else suggested, use a module to populate and store the environmental variables.)

If not, my suggestion would be to use create a class method that you would use to populate a dictionary of the environmental variables in your classes the first time `__init__` is called for each of them.